# Congnos Ranking lowest as Rank 1

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8, ranking-functions

I am having hard time to rank lowest average number as rank 1, currently it ranking highest average number  as rank 1. My current formula see below,

```
rank([Total Average], [Store Number])
```

I want it like below picture. How should I do that? Any help will be really appreciate. Thank you

[image]

Comment: I'm sure you tried this but let just to be sure. Did you try adding ASC to the function?

Comment: rank([Total Average], [Store Number] DESC). Note that the store number will effectively break any ties.

Comment: @Johnsonium, I did this `rank([Total Average], [Store Number] DESC)` Does not do anything. I wonder why is that.

Comment: I'm not sure. I created a sample report to make sure I was correct before commenting and it worked for me.

Comment: @Johnsonium, you are correct your one work, but I figure it out why my one is not working. My total average is a query calculations (`(
[Post Paid Voice Gross Adds Rank LY] + [Prepaid Actual Rank LY] + [Accessory GP Rank LY] +  [DTV Now Rank LY] + [Premium Video Rank LY] + [IPBB Rank LY] + [WTR Rank LY] + [IRPO Rank LY] )/8`). When I removed /8 it works fine. I am not sure why is that tho. Anyway Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @AquaticallyChallengedFish, Thank you so much for the help.